# Using whole row in Row Level Security policy

Tags: postgresql, syntax, row-level-security, policy-based-management

I am using row level security with function, for example

```
CREATE POLICY person_select_policy ON core.person FOR SELECT USING (core.person_policy_check(id, 'read') = TRUE);
```

Is it possible to pass **whole row** to the function? So the function would have access to all columns of the row without having to name them all as arguments. That way the function could accept `core.person` as parameter or at least a record type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Declare a parameter with the type of the table:

```
create function core.person_policy_check(p_row core.person, p_access text)
  returns boolean
as
$$
begin
  if p_row.id = 42 then ..
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then pass the row to the function:

```
CREATE POLICY person_select_policy 
   ON core.person 
   FOR SELECT USING (core.person_policy_check(person, 'read') = TRUE);
```

Comment: this is great, thanks a lot.